# Java 2D page-flipping on Linux

Tags: java, linux, java-2d, tearing, double-buffering

Our Java 2D application exhibits screen tearing when run on Linux.  It does not exhibit any tearing when running on Windows.  We've spent significant time analyzing our code, and haven't yet found a cause there.  While I'm never one to decide that it must not be my code at fault, I'm also entertaining the possibility that the issue is with the Java 2D rendering pipeline on Linux.  By the way, please note that we see the tearing with both Java 6 and Java 7.  When running on Java 7, we see the tearing regardless of whether we enable the XRender pipeline or not.

We are of course using double-buffering via a `BufferStrategy`.  The `BufferStrategy` implementation we get when we call `Frame.createBufferStrategy(2)` is a `java.awt.Component$FlipSubRegionBufferStrategy`.  In addition, calling `isPageFlipping()` on the `BufferStrategy`'s `BufferCapabilities` returns true, and calling `isFullScreenRequired()` on the capabilities returns false.  We are not running in full-screen exclusive mode, though we have tried doing so and it did not resolve the issue.  `BufferCapabilities.getFlipContents()` returns `FlipContents.UNDEFINED` (but I suspect that is not relevant).

Since page-flipping is supposedly supported and we're getting a page-flipping `BufferStrategy` (rather than a blitting strategy), I would not expect the rendering pipeline to be causing the tearing.  However, I found a mailing list message written by Chet Haase back in 2006 addressing a screen tearing problem which states, "It's possible that the Flip strategy on your particular platform is actually doing a copy behind the scenes, which would be the same as the BltBufferStrategy, which runs smack into the refresh artifact."

**How can I determine if the flip strategy we're getting is not actually page-flipping?**

Chet also states, "Running fullscreen with a BufferStrategy is a decent way to work around this; depending on the platform and the situation, we will usually give you a Flip strategy, which is (usually) synchronized with the vertical refresh of the display to avoid tearing."

**How can I determine if the strategy is synchronized with the display's vertical refresh?**

(See http://www.mail-archive.com/java2d-interest@capra.eng.sun.com/msg03743.html for the full message from Chet Haase referenced above)

Comment: on its 2D pipeline, jdk 7 can take advantage of Xrender,it'd be interesting if that gives different result.  You have to pass `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=True` as a vm argument to enable it.

Comment: Any other graphichal application tears on linux?

Comment: nos: Sorry to say that we are using the XRender pipeline (please see the last sentence of the first paragraph of my question).

Comment: Seyfülislam: Good question, and the answer is no.  For example, viewing a video using VLC or Totem does not exhibit tearing, despite that being a common problem for video playback!

Comment: @misterbiscuit, Many graphics cards have mp4 playback hardware acceleration built-in, I'd be astonished if VLC or Totem didn't take advantage of them considering their maturity as applications.  That said, I've seen tearing (in non-video areas) combined with smooth video playback, so odds are it is some combination of X network latency combined with some composting, perhaps a desktop that assumes 3d acceleration when it's not really 100% functional?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the distro, many Linux systems are now shipping desktops that are 3d rendered by default.  If you have one of the graphics cards which has poor (or missing) 3d acceleration with open-source drivers, you may need to install a proprietary 3d driver to get the desktop rendering within the acceptance tolerances for normal desktop use.

Remember that if your code looks right on other platforms, and performs admirably there; odds are it is right on Linux.  It's just that Linux has a lot more "rendering architecture" variance, as would be expected considering X's history and design goals.  Chances are your graphics information is being sent in a timely manner, but the config pipeline just can't keep up (so it drops a little, resulting in tearing).

Now for the specific questions

**How can I determine if the flip strategy we're getting is not actually page-flipping?**

By calling the methods you have already called.

**How can I determine if the strategy is synchronized with the display's vertical refresh?**

Hard to say, because the entire point of the strategy is to hide the nasty details from the API user.  I'm not the right person to dive under these covers; but, I do have a good view of things from the X side.

My question to you, "Does this tearing exhibit in any other application besides your own?"

Comment: We are using nVidia's proprietary driver.  As for the first question, what I was really driving at is that I suspect we might not be getting page-flipping even though the Java API tells us we are (based on comments by Chet Haase sent to a mailing list years ago).  I'm not seeing tearing in any other application.

Comment: To further complicate matters: in one case, the Linux system we're on is not running a desktop environment nor window manager of any kind.  Instead, it runs our application directly (via the xinitrc).  So that takes the DE out of the equation, but we still see tearing.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered that the issue may be that on windows you are using oracle jdk and on linux you are using open jdk?

Its easy to find out. Install oracle jdk on your linux machine and run against the oracle jre.

Instructions on how to install [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre)

Details on how to switch between installed versions of jre [here](http://digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)

Comment: It's been a long time, but if I remember correctly we were using Oracle's JDK/JRE on both operating systems.